# Long-time execution php script reset after 30 sec

Tags: php, apache, timeout, wamp

I have a php script which involves a lot of work with my mysql data base, as it should generate a school schedule, but after aprox 30-40 sec of exec , it is reset and after other 30-40 sec my browser shows me the message:

> This web page is unavailable.

I tried every method I found on the internet ( php.ini - `max_execution_time` , `set_time_limit(0)` , `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10)`) , even changed the timeout of apache, but still my script is reset. Any ideas?

EDIT

```
[01-Mar-2015 15:30:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic    library 'E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

in Unknown on line 0

[01-Mar-2015 15:30:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

in Unknown on line 0

[01-Mar-2015 15:30:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[01-Mar-2015 15:30:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

This is my php error log, after a reset. Does it afect in any way my script?

Comment: Maybe it's about memory. Try to increase you memory limit maybe ? ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

Comment: it has already been set at 512M, just in case..

Comment: To be sure what the problem actually is, look in the Apache error log as well as the PHP error log. If it is a timeout I would expect to see a message saying so in one of those log files, If you dont see a timeout message then it is probablky not a timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly those error messages in the php error log are probably not related to this issue but can be sorted out by doing this.

```
left click on the wampmanager icon in the system tray
wampmanager->Apache->Version->2.4.9 ( click on the 2.4.9 version number )
```

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild all the SYMLINKS in the `\apache2.4.9\bin` folder.

Comment: could it be from the number of queries I'm using to build the schedule? I use very large number of queries, like 1000 till the script stop working. Now the problem is that the script is running for a while, shows me a part of the results, it's still loading, but the data base is no longer modifed